# Gitlab - manual job blocking merge request

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I set up various manual job that are optionals:

[image]

The problem is like I didn't have a success on this optional jobs I can't merge :

[image]

**EDIT**

The solution was to put `allow_failure: true`